# What's the difference between "parliament" and "congress"

Tags: differences

Is there any differences between these two words? Thanks

Comment: Of course there is. For starters, some countries have the one, others have the other. Have you ever heard of the US Parliament? Or the UK Congress?

Comment: As a first approximation there is little difference.  Political theorists could give you a basic distinction, but in pretty much all cases the details are spelled out in the government's organizing statutes (such as the US Constitution), so one could easily have a given legislative body called "congress" that is close to the British Parliament in operation, or a body called "parliament" which is close to the US Congress in operation.

Comment: (I recently read somewhere that the authors of the US Constitution chose to name the legislative body "Congress" rather than "Parliament" because they wanted the legislators to not get swelled heads, and "congress" was (at the time) a sort of "blah" term.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They refer to two different [democratic systems](http://study.com/academy/lesson/congress-vs-parliament-main-differences.html) but they  both are  representative bodies with supreme legislative powers within a state.

> - ***Parliamentary democracy and congressional democracy are two systems of government that are utilized in democratic governments.***
> - ***Parliamentary democracy*** is a system of democratic governance in which the executive branch is held accountable to the legislative branch and the head of government is almost always a member of the legislature. The Parliament is the legislative branch of a parliamentary democracy. This type of democracy is found in Britain and in free, independent countries that Britain used to rule.
> - Conversely, a ***congressional democracy*** is a system of democratic governance in which the executive branch is separate from the legislative branch and the head of government is not a member of the legislature. The Congress is the legislative branch of a congressional democracy. This type of democracy is found in the United States and a few other democratic countries.
> - While these two systems of government have similarities, they also have a few very important differences.

(study.com/academy)